# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression on second button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, error-handling, jscript

hi I have log in Partial view in jquery dialog , when I click button for the first time, it works true. It means that, if textboxes are empty then it shows client errors to fill them. but when I click the second time, if textboxes fill or not , it shows this error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized
>   expression: #

how can i do?

**edited:**

by clicking on this button, jquery dialog is been shown:

```
  <div class="buttons">          @{
        if (Session["member"] != null)
        {

                <input type="button" value="خريد" class="btn" id="btnn" onclick="addToOrders(@item.themesModel.ThemeID, true)" />
        }
        else
        {

                <input type="button" value="خريد" class="btn" id="btnn" onclick="addToOrders(@item.themesModel.ThemeID,false)" />

        }
```

this is js code to show jq dialog:

```
function addToOrders(themeId, user) {

    var inputParams = "{themeId : '" + themeId + "'}";
    if (user==true) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Members/buy/Index',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: inputParams,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (mm) {

                $("#resultMessage").dialog({
                    show: "puff",
                    hide: "puff",
                    resizable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    position: "center",
             width: 280,
             height: 250,
                });
                $("#resultMessage").dialog().addClass(".ui-dialog");
                $("#resultMessage").html(mm);
            }
        });

    }
    else {

        $("#resultMessage")
         .dialog({
             show: "puff",
             hide: "puff",
             resizable: false,
             modal: true,
             position: "center",
             title:"Login"
         })
          .load('/Members/MemberLoginPartial/LoginUser');       
    }
}
```

this is my button code in login partial view that is rendered in dialog:

```
 <input type="submit" value="login" />
```

and these are scripts that i have used in main layout:

```
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/SlideMain/jquery.easyAccordion.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/SlideMain/utility.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/Members/Members.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: How you think someone would know the answer without seeing the code.

Comment: which part of code i should copy here?

Comment: Hmm... The eventhandler function for the second click would be nice...

Comment: Where does the error occur? Is it in your code or the JQuery library? In Internet Explorer you can press F12 to open the debugger. In the debugger after clicking on "script" (left top second menu layer) there is a button "start debugging"

Comment: in IE debugger, by clicking on "start debugging" i got this error:
**"Unable to attach to process.Another debugger might be attached to the process;"**
when above error occures,"jquery-1.5.1.js" is opened and error is shown on this part:
      '// We have to add a catch block for
      // IE prior to 8 or else the finally
      // block will never get executed
      catch (e) {
       throw e;'